# Passing a variable of type int to a parentViewController [iOS]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am building an iPad application that uses Jeremy Fox's `JFDepthView` library. For those that aren't familiar it basically allows a new view controller to brought front and center, sending the parent view to the background and applying a blurring algorithm to it to bring the user focus to the presented top view. That all works perfectly but I am having issues setting the value of an int and passing it back to the `parentViewController` from the presented topView.

I have `TTViewController` which is the originating view controller. A button is tapped on this view and `JFDepthView` kicks in and presents a new view on top of `TTViewController` called `IndustryViewController`. When a button on `IndustryViewController` is tapped I want that view to be dismissed and a specific action to happen on the parent `TTViewController` depending on the `int` passed back that I set when the button is pressed.

I have created a property for my int in the originating (parent) viewController.

```
@interface TTViewController : UIViewController <JFDepthViewDelegate> {

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int          defence;

@end
```

In my child view controller (the one presented over the top by JFDepthView) I am trying to gain access to the parent and set the value of the variable then dismiss the view.

```
@implementation IndustryViewController

- (IBAction)defenceBtnPressed:(id)sender
{
    TTViewController *viewController = (TTViewController *)self.parentViewController;
    viewController.defence = 1;
    [self.depthViewReference dismissPresentedViewInView:self.presentedInView animated:YES];
}
```

I get no errors or warnings, everything builds fine. But the value of the int 'defence' is always 0. I am obviously doing something wrong and have a lack of understanding of the parentViewController setup. Can anyone fill in the blanks or point me in the right direction?

EDIT: It seems that if I log out `parentViewController` and `presentingViewController` they are both `NULL`. I have also logged out the defence variable immediately after setting it and it never actually gets set to '1'.

Comment: Have you verified that `self.parentViewController` is not nil?

Comment: Did you `@synthesize defence`?

Comment: self.parentViewController is (TTViewController *)

Comment: Xcode auto synthesizes properties

Comment: Where are you checking if defence is set to 1?

Comment: Tom - I'm checking in TTViewController in the one of JFDepthView's delegate methods. When the presented view is dismissed I am checking on the view that the property has been set in.

Comment: If I log the defence variable out immediately after trying to set it then it is also 0 so it never actually gets set to 1

Comment: Stupid question: Is your `-defenceBtnPressed:` method being called when your button is tapped?

Comment: @trudyscousin - Yes, the method is being called. It dismisses the view perfectly as I want. In fact, if I actually set the code I want to execute based on the defence variable to '0' then everything works perfectly. So everything else is functioning fine.

Comment: In one of your comments to tom, you mentioned that your `parentViewController` is nil. Saying `viewController.defence = 1` is like saying, under the older syntax, `[viewController setDefence:1]` In other words, you're sending a message to nil. No crash, but nothing happens. You need to find out why it's nil.

Comment: @trudyscousin Yes, i just discovered it was nil. Im looking into that right now.

Comment: What code is used to present the IndustryViewController? You won't necessarily have a parent or a presenting view controller, depending on how the presentation was done.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `self.parentViewController` is `nil`. I conjecture that JFDepthView doesn't set the `parentViewController` automatically for you.

If `self.depthViewReference` is the parent view controller (i.e. the one on which you called `presentViewController:xxx inView:self.view` to present the current VC), then simplify cast it to the desired class `TTViewController` and set `defence = 1` on that.

Comment: self.parentViewController is (TTViewController *) so it isn't nil as far as I can see. presentViewController fails also with defence int still being passed as 0

Comment: Actually, when checking again. parentViewController and presentingViewController are both NULL